# Create reusable 'base code' using MVC2-RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to write a simple library for MVC2 projects that takes care of user login, e-mail validation, password recovery, etc. Since some of these steps involve user interaction, I need to have Views and Controllers in that project.

In MVC2 Preview 2, one could do this by abusing areas (at least, it seems) since they were implemented in different projects. However, in RC a new area will merely create a subfolder. Since I want to share the base code between applications, that is not an option.

I tried to brutally hack the AfterBuild steps into my project files, but that doesn't 'feel right' (I wouldn't sleep another night :)

Could you share some thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might be a duplicate of [Areas over multiple projects - Views not found in child projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838629/areas-over-multiple-projects-views-not-found-in-child-projects)

The build task to copy the views have been moved to the `Mvc.Futures` project. Other options to solve the problem include defining the views in the application, even when they are being referred to by controllers in the library. Also, the MvcContrib project offers portable areas.

A thorough explanation by Phil Haack can be found at http://forums.asp.net/p/1494640/3540105.aspx