# Setup Multiple Project Areas with Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to go through the 'Multiple Project Areas' with MVC 2.0 in VS2010. I have looked at the 'Portable Areas' from MvcContrib and cannot get that to work right... the examples do not match the source code files... and furthermore the way it is done is just excessively difficult to use.

I have been following this tutorial, for the moment : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx

But it is for Visual Studio 2008, and the last part of it requires some changes to the csproj files. These lines that it expects do not exist.

Does anyone know how to complete this and make Multiple Project Areas work properly?

I discovered this question : [Areas over multiple projects - Views not found in child projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838629/areas-over-multiple-projects-views-not-found-in-child-projects)

That touches on this; Though the answer doesn't explain HOW to do this with MvcFutures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987(VS.100).aspx is out of date.

Unfortunately, it appears that the multi-project area support was removed before MVC 2 went RTM, but you may be able to use one of the work-arounds discussed here: forums.asp.net/p/1516088/3712011.aspx

Aside from that, the only ways that I've found to get multi-project MVC to work has been using Portable Areas or MEF (blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx and http://mef.codeplex.com/.

I'm just getting into evaluating these two solutions myself, but I've seen them referenced over and over for this problem area.